# assign meta data to resource?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to associate some meta data with my image resource

```
var res=ResourceLoader.load("res://some_img.png")
res.set_meta("data","value")
```

so whenever I load the image from any node it can access the meta data,
but it doesn't seem to be working, doesn't [`resource`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resource.html) inherit from [`Object`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object)?

**Edit:**

Maybe acceess the `some_img.png.import` file?
it does seem to have `metadata={ "vram_texture": false }`

Comment: As far as I can tell metadata on these resources is not persisted. I.e. the matadata would be in RAM but not saved. I guess you would need your own solution to save them.

Comment: Another point of view is that Resources are References which are reference counted. If `res` goes out of scope and there are no other references to `some_img.png` then that reference is destroyed along with your meta data. If one ref is kept alive _somewhere_ you can access that meta data from anywhere.